# putting PHP within JavaScript gives an error about a missing )

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, syntax-error

This is the meat of a response from an successful ajax query:

```
if (data.tx) {

          document.cookie = "tx = " + data.tx;

          $('#fortune').empty().append('<?php foreach ($out_rows as $out => $rows) { $metadata = json_decode($rows["metadata"], true); $id = json_decode($rows["id"], true); if ($id["id"] == $_COOKIE["tx"]) { $card = $metadata["6770"]["map"][0]["k"]["string"]; $fortune = $metadata["6770"]["map"][0]["v"]["string"]; $direction = $metadata["6770"]["map"][1]["v"]["string"]; $image = $metadata["6770"]["map"][1]["k"]["string"]; if ($direction == "up") { ?> <div class="row"> <div class="col s12 m2"> </div> <div class="col s12 m8 center-align"> <div class="col s12 m12" style="color: #F8F3E5; background-color: #D5302F; padding: 1em; margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em: "> <h2><?php echo $card; ?></h2> </div> <div class="col s12 m12" style="background-color: #F8F3E5;"> <img src="https://fortunes.coconutpool.com/img/<?php echo $image; ?>" style=" margin: 2em; width: 35%; height: 35%;"> </div> <div class="col s12 m12" style="background-color: #FDEAA7; padding: 1em;"> <p style="font-size: 20px;">Today you may feel.. </p> <p style="font-size: 20px;"><?php echo $fortune; ?></p> <p><button class=\"btn\" onClick=\"window.location.href=window.location.href\">Get Another Fortune</button></p> </div> </div> <div class="col s12 m2"> </div> </div> <?php } if ($direction == "down") { ?> <div class="row"> <div class="col s12 m2"> </div> <div class="col s12 m8 center-align"> <div class="col s12 m12" style="color: #F8F3E5; background-color: #D5302F; padding: 1em; margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em: "> <h2><?php echo $card; ?></h2> </div> <div class="col s12 m12" style="background-color: #F8F3E5;"> <img src="https://fortunes.coconutpool.com/img/<?php echo $image; ?>" style=" margin: 2em; transform: rotate(180deg); width: 35%; height: 35%;"> </div> <div class="col s12 m12" style="background-color: #FDEAA7; padding: 1em;"> <p style="font-size: 20px;">Today you may feel.. </p> <p style="font-size: 20px;"><?php echo $fortune; ?></p> <p><button class="btn" onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href">Get Another Fortune</button></p> </div> </div> <div class="col s12 m2"> </div> </div> <?php } }}?>');
        }
      }
```

my problem is here: `if ($id["id"] == $_COOKIE["tx"])` where i want to compare the cookies value ot the looping values. if i put in just a plain text string for where the $_COOKIE["tx"] is everything works fine.

But with it the way it is I get the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

JavaScript is a mystery to me, so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You missed the ending bracket of foreach loop

Comment: Please properly indent that PHP code

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets are miss-paired. It is not good for `html/js` code with `php` code mixed.

You can using some popular frontend framework like `Vue/React` and restful backend framework like `Laravel/Yii2` with json-api supported.

Maybe you should reorganize your code like these:

```php
<?php
// php code with variables defines and updates
$title = "TO DO LIST";
$linked = "";
$todos = ["Shopping", "Learning html", "Cooking"];
foreach ($todos as $todo) {
  $linked .= "<li>".$todo."</li>".PHP_EOL;
}
$addonTask = "Watching NEWS";
// html template
$html = <<<HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>$title</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>$title</h1>
    <div class="to-do-list">
        <ul id="items">
            $linked
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#items').append('<li>$addonTask</li>');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
HTML;

echo $html;
```